# @Autowired can't find Repository bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a Crud Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface SampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Metadata, String> {
     findById(UUID id);
}

I am trying to use it in my test class which is in another package
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class SampleRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private SampleRepository sampleRepository;
```

Its says No bean definition with SampleRepository found. Can anyone help me why I can't autowire this repository

Comment: Does your `TestConfig` class enable Spring Data JPA and perform repo scanning?

Comment: Kinda need to see that config. (And the `@Repository` is completely unnecessary.)

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to inject dependency in Junit test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823045/unable-to-inject-dependency-in-junit-test)

Comment: there must be some where to use the @ComponentScan  annotation.    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "xxx.xxx.xxx")

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments: @Repository is not needed for your SampleRepository.
@WebAppConfiguration on the test is also looks weird. But both of these are OK.

More important: even if you are not provided your TestContext.java file it should be like that:

```
@Configuration
// be sure to provide base package where your repostories are located
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {
    "com.acme.repositories"
})
public class TestContext {
  // your datasource
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
  }

  // your entity manager factory
  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    // your domain classes package
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.acme.domain");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();

    return factory.getObject();
  }

  // your jpa transaction manager
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return txManager;
  }
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue of jpa repository not getting autowired. I can say that non-other worked for me except this. `EnableJpaRepositories` was the key. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

@Repository is not necessary. You code should be this:

```
public interface SampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Metadata, String> {
 @Query(value = "select * from db.tabel where id = :id", nativeQuery = true)
 findById(@Param("id") UUID id);
 }
```